# Javascript keyboard, shift + key combo

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I'm creating a on-screen-keyboard in vanilla Javascript and I'm trying to change the color of the on-screen-keyboard-keys when the same keys are pressed on the physical keyboard. So far so good. The problem is, I am using keyup and keydown, but I can't seem to get the shift-combos right.

This is whats going to happen:

- When a normal key is pressed it changes color to blue.
- When the shift-key is pressed it changes color to red.
- When the shift-key + a key is pressed, both of them is going to be red, and when the key is released it is going back to normal, but if the shift-key is still being held down it will have the color red.

Problem: When the shift-key is pressed + a normal key, the color on both buttons will dissapear if I release the normal key, even if the shift-key is still pressed.

This is my code so far:

```
farge1 = ' key-pressed';
farge2 = ' shift-pressed';
shift = false;




var klikk = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var k = e.keyCode || e.which;

if (k === 13) {
    document.getElementById('enter').className += (farge1);
} else if (k === 8) {
    document.getElementById('backspace').className += (farge1);
} else if (k === 16) {
    document.getElementById('shift-right').className += (farge2);
    document.getElementById('shift-left').className += (farge2);
    shift = true;
}

};

var bokstav = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var b = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();

if (shift === true) {
    document.getElementById(b).className += (farge2);
} else {
    document.getElementById(b).className += (farge1);
}
};


var slipp = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
var b = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();

document.getElementById('enter').className = ("");
document.getElementById('backspace').className = ("");

document.getElementById(b).className = ("");
if (k !== 16) {
    document.getElementById('shift-left').className = ("");
    document.getElementById('shift-right').className = ("");
}
shift = false;

};


document.onkeypress = bokstav;
document.onkeydown = klikk;
document.onkeyup = slipp;
```

I'm totally new at this.. No jQuery pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an error in it, that is caused by the keypress event. The event is continuously firing whenever you are holding the shift key down. However, `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` will always return an empty string for Shift, which is not a printable character. You need to add logic to your keypress event to handle shift:

```
var bokstav = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var b = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();

    if (b) { // make sure b has a value
        if (shift === true) {
            document.getElementById(b).className += (farge2);
        } else {
            document.getElementById(b).className += (farge1);
        }
    }
};
```

To prevent shift from changing on a normal keyup:

```
document.getElementById(b).className = ("");
if (k === 16) {
    document.getElementById('shift-left').className = ("");
    document.getElementById('shift-right').className = ("");
    shift = false;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUf6G/). This will only work for the 'a' or 'shift' + 'a' presses.

Comment: Thx, but I think it's the keyup that's the problem, it's on the release of a normal key the shift-color dissapears.. I can't wrap my head around the logic because of my lack of syntax-skills

Comment: @HåvardBrynjulfsen it's because you are checking the keyup for !== 16. You should only change the shift color back on === 16.